# Automatically Sending Notification Email w/ Server

Tags: javascript, email, server, notifications, automation

I need to do a notification sender working on a linux server. The idea is once a week this sender do a query in JQL and, if it returns something, sends an email to a certain list.
I'm rather new to servers and javascript. I'm already doing the JQL query, but:

1. I need the Sender to know the right time to do it. What is the most efficient way to trigger the Sender?
2. How can I send an email in JS from an specific address to a list of emails?

A rough sketch:

```js
//magic, part 1

WaitUntilMonday();

var result = DoJQLQuery();

if (result != '')
  SendNotificationEmail(from,to,message);
  
//magic, part 2
```

I tried to search about it, but I don´t know where to start. I´d appreciate any suggest of reading material too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use NODEJS with sendgrid api for your server end and email api. The actual clientside, you could hook it up to a on a website or simply just run the nodejs application.
So the place to start would be https://nodejs.org/ and http://sendgrid.com
That would definitely handle your emailing needs. Here is a function I used stripped of my api key (obviously), the call to postEmail actually sends the mail, the rest is verification.
to send email its pretty easy. Good luck.

```
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = "SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
var sg = require('sendgrid')(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
var emptyRequest = require('sendgrid-rest').request;
var request = require("request");
    function makeEmail(whereFrom, whereTo, mysubject, mycontent){
      from_email = new helper.Email(whereFrom);
      to_email = new helper.Email(whereTo);
      subject = mysubject;
      content = new helper.Content("text/html", mycontent);

      mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);
      custom_arg = new helper.CustomArgs("OURGUID", "ourcustomarg");
      mail.addCustomArg(custom_arg);
      var finished = mail.toJSON();


      var timer = 0;

      function postEmail(){
          var requestBody = finished;
          var requestPost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyRequest));
          requestPost.method = 'POST';
          requestPost.path = '/v3/mail/send';
          requestPost.body = requestBody;
          sg.API(requestPost, function (error, response) {
            console.log(response.statusCode + ' STATUS')
             console.log('MESSAGE ID = '+ response.headers['x-message-id']) 
            if(response.statusCode == '202') {
              console.log(response.statusCode + ' EMAIL SENT TO SENDGRID AND QUED')
                          }//response if statement
          if(response.statusCode != '202'){
            console.log(response.statusCode + ' Something went wrong')}
                          })//end internal api function
            }//end api

    postEmail(finished);//actually sending the mail

      function getEmail(){
          var requestBody = finished;
          var requestPost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emptyRequest));
          requestPost.method = 'GET';
          requestPost.path = '/v3/mail/send';
          requestPost.body = requestBody;
          sg.API(requestPost, function (error, response) {
            console.log(response.statusCode + ' SUCCESSFUL EMAIL');
             console.log('MESSAGE ID = '+ response.headers['x-message-id']) ;
                        })//end internal api function
            }//end api  


          function checkBounce(){
            console.log('this is checkBounce');
          var options = { method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/bounces/'+ whereTo,
            headers: { authorization: 'Bearer your api key here' },
            body: '{}' };

          request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(body);
          });
          }//check Bounce


          function checkInvalid(){
            console.log('This is check invalid');
          var options = { method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/invalid_emails'+ whereTo,
            headers: { authorization: 'Bearer your api key here' },
            body: '{}' };

          request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(response.statusCode);
            console.log(body);
          });

          }//check Invalid

          function checkBlock(){
            console.log('This is check Block');
            var options = { method: 'GET',
             url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/suppression/blocks'+ whereTo,
             headers: { authorization: 'Bearer your api key here' },
             body: '{}' };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
              if (error) throw new Error(error);
              console.log(response.statusCode);
              console.log(body.created);
          });

          }//check Block



    function checkTest(){
            console.log('This is check Test');
            var options = { method: 'GET',
             url: 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/',

             headers: { authorization: 'Bearer your api key here' },
             body: '{}' };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
              if (error) throw new Error(error);
              body = JSON.parse(body);
              console.log(response.statusCode);
              console.log(body);



          });//end request


          }//check Processed

    }//make email end
```